# Complex integral on path C: $\int_{C}\cos\left(z^2\right) +\left(z^*\right)^2\mathrm{d}z.$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, complex-integration

I got this integral on my exercises list, but I think the professor misspelled the integral
$$\int_{C}\cos\left(z^2\right) +\left(z^*\right)^2\mathrm{d}z.$$
I interpreted it as
$$\int_{C}\cos\left(z^2\right)\mathrm{d}z +\int_{C}\left(z^*\right)^2\mathrm{d}z,$$
but I don't know if is right; I could not solve this integral closed rectangle with counterclockwise direction and vertices
$z_1=1$
$z_2=1+i$
$z_3=-1+i$
$z_4=-1$

Comment: Is C the closed rectangle you're talking about?

Comment: Why can you not compute the integral?